# Why is video scrubbing using currentTime linked to scroll events choppy on Firefox but not Safari?

Tags: firefox, video, scroll

When I experience https://video-scrub.playground.ghosh.dev/video-current-time/ on Firefox, scroll-based playback is choppy, but playback on Safari is excellent.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that the reason the behaviour is different on the different browsers is probably because the h264 codec, and/or how the browser uses the decoder, is different between them.

The reason why it is stuttering on Firefox is likely a bug which is worth flagging on the Firefox issue tracker - you may find there is already a workaround, e.g. see this similar issue previously which gives good insight into the HW vs SW acceleration also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1513511

If you look at the encoding of the video in your clip you can see it is h264 - output from ffprobe:

> Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 1135 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 48k tbn (default)

Because h264 is not a 'free' as in patent free technology, Firefox has some history with its support. Originally it was not supported at all, but in early 2010's support was added provided the underlying platform supported it. In 2013 (I think) Firefox added SW codec support built in using the Cisco supplied royalty free openH264 codec, but AFAIK (its hard to keep up...) this is only used as a fallback if ffmpeg is not available on the host OS, which is the preferred and generally better performing approach. Too make it even more confusing it reportedly used to be the case, and possibly still is, that openH264 was used for encoding and ffmpeg, if available, for decoding.

It may be worth checking the nightly Firefox build also if you do find it is a reported issue as fixes will find their way there quicker, usually.